# How can I save a Google map as a SVG image?

Tags: pdf, svg, google-maps

I want to convert the image here: http://scimaps.org/maps/map/map_of_complexity_sc_154/detail to a SVG or PDF file. Using print from Firefox doesn't work. What are my options?

Comment: You could first get the map as PNG and then vectorize the image to SVG. Keep in mind that the images are copyrighted and an SVG could be a derivative work (which you are not allowed to create).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have permission to do so from the content owner and are not creating copyright issues for yourself or others you share it with, you can just zoom out to appropriate resolution, and screen scrape chunks of the image (in Windows ctrl+alt+print screen will capture the current window in focus to your clipboard) then paste and  re-stitch the images back together in MS paint or your most favored photo imaging tool.  You can then save the file off to whatever format you please once in paint or print it to a pdf if you have a pdf driver.

Comment: While a way to do something similar, this doesn't really provide the benefit an SVG does, as resizing an SVG doesn't degrade the quality of it

Answer (score 1):

(I am basing my answer on [this Wayback Machine snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20160418121255/http://scimaps.org/maps/map/map_of_complexity_sc_154/detail) because the original page no longer exists. The current URL of the successor page is https://scimaps.org/map/9/5)

The page you link to is using a (now-deprecated, I believe) Google Maps library where you could put your own bitmap tiles inside. It is the same library that drove Legacy Google Maps.

Google Maps (the service) does not expose the map vectors in a way that could easily be saved. This could only possibly work using hacks.

Modern Google Maps (with “smooth zooming”) is fully vector-based, *however* the Maps Javascript application displays these vectors in a `<canvas>` element. What the browser eventually gets is again a bitmap (simply put). Legacy Google Maps is based on bitmap tiles, like most web maps today. Your browser never even sees the underlying vectors. They need not even exist on the server.

**tl;dr:** Not possible. Maybe ask the original authors of the map.